# app store not showing app that have correct keywords

Tags: ios, app-store, keyword

I have an app named "4SaleQ8". I have added keywords and one of the keyword says "4sale"

However when I search on app store with 4sale, it is not showing my application.

Any idea why this is happening?

App link is as below.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/4saleq8/id1066646920?mt=8

If I search for 4saleq8, 4 sale q8 it show but it if I search for 4sale, it don't show

### *I don't want to search on Google... I am talking of search on App Store.*

Comment: @BadalShah : nope.. [this is my app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/4saleq8/id1066646920?mt=8)

Comment: @BadalShah : also I upload the app before few weeks... all of sudden client came and asking why it is not showing even it is there in keywords list...

Answer (score 0):

As part of the approval process, Apple reviewers can remove some of the keywords that you submit if they deem them inappropriate, for example if they match a competitor's name.

Some advice on this is [here](https://sensortower.com/blog/what-to-do-when-apple-deletes-app-store-keywords-without-telling-you).

Comment: I would think it would be removed from there. Have you considered contacting Apple to figure it out? You get two technical support incidents as part of the annual developer subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Ranking on a specific keyword will not happen in one night. There are a lot of factors that affects your rankings.From on-page ASO, off-page ASO, Keyword Optimization, and ratings and reviews.

I would suggest you to read these two useful articles to help you guide rank your app:

- [17 Free Ways To Find New Keywords For Your App](https://www.appmarketingboost.com/free-app-keyword-tools/)
- [10 Basic Things You Should Know About ASO](https://www.appmarketingboost.com/basic-app-store-optimization/)